# How to get Invoice ID on Payment

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, invoice, sales

In my Magento 1.9 installation I have an observer that observes the event `sales_order_invoice_pay`. When this event triggers I'm attempting to store the invoice's ID in a custom model I've created.

Here's how I'm getting the invoice from the event: `$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();`

However, when I attempt this using: `getId()`, `getData('entity_id')`, `getIncrementId()`, or `getOrigData('entity_id')`, I receive a `null` value.

It's important for me to store this specific invoice id as I'm using it later to load that invoice and create a shipment for items invoiced.

Is there anyway for me to get the ID?

Answer (score 0):

In your observer method you can do:

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
```

From this variable you get all the invoice data

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not being specific enough in my question, but I'm already getting that from the observer. The problem is that getting the id from that object is returning `null`

Comment: @RyanScottCady did you try using sales_order_invoice_save_after ?

Comment: That event isn't available in Magento 1.9. Even if it was, that event would not be a good way as it updates every time the invoice saves, NOT when it's paid

Comment: @RyanScottCady true that (pretty sure it's available as a dynamic event)

Comment: @RyanScottCady what about sales_order_invoice_register ?

Comment: I actually just tried that and, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: @RyanScottCady it should work with this one and getId though. Are you sure your observer is getting called?

Comment: I'll have to try it again. Once I find out I'll let ya know!

Comment: yeah that didn't work. What am I doing wrong? lol

Answer (score 0):

This is the same case as happened to me [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173220/sales-order-invoice-save-after-event-issue)

You'd observe **sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after** event, at this point invoice should be totally saved, so you could get `entity_id` value