# Sales Order Invoice - save_after event getId() issue

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, invoice

I need to manipulate invoice items & some other data after the invoice is created, so I've used **sales_order_invoice_save_after** event.

I know this event is fired more than just when creating the invoice, so most people recommend using other events such as **sales_order_invoice_pay**, but that's not a problem for my needs.

My surprise has came when debugging why things don't work as expected, and I've found that it seems this event is fired **before** the invoice is totally saved

For instance, inside the observer...

```
$invoice->getData() // returns some data, but...
$invoice->getId() // returns nothing ¿¿??
```

If I look database, there is no record in **sales_flat_invoice** table

Anybody here has faced the same issue? So, which event could I use to get the invoice object **after** it is saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fired after the save action, but before data is commited. `sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after` should do the job.

In `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` you can see whats the difference is between `_save_before`, `_save_after` and `_save_commit_after` events are:

```
/**
 * Save object data
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public function save()
{
    ...
    try {
        $this->_beforeSave();
        if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
            $this->_getResource()->save($this);
            $this->_afterSave();
        }
        $this->_getResource()->addCommitCallback(array($this, 'afterCommitCallback'))
            ->commit();
        ...
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Callback function which called after transaction commit in resource model
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public function afterCommitCallback()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_commit_after', array('object'=>$this));
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_commit_after', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: nice! I will try & give you feedback